# Find document that matches same array elements in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Think of these documents in MongoDB:

```
{id:1, people:['james', 'john', 'candy']}
{id:2, people:['james', 'john', 'candy', 'gary']}
```

How can I find document that match only **full set** of array elements, regardless of the order of array elements.

For example if I input this:

```
input=[ 'candy', 'james', 'john' ]
```

The matching response should be document `id:1`.

If I had any other documents with exact same 3 people, regardless of their order in MongoDB `people` array, it should also match.

I've tried `$all`, but this did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/size/) to limit the array's size：

```js
db.test.find({
   "people": { $all: [ 'james', 'john', 'candy' ], $size: 3 }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

As a solution to your problem please try executing following query in mongodb.

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({"people":{$all:[ 'james', 'john', 'candy' ]}})
```

The above query will perform exact match of array elements regardless of their order